# Как удалить файл из проекта .csproj не используя Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

Что нужно подправить в файле проекта .csproj, чтобы удалить исходный файл из проекта С# и чтобы после удаления этого исходного файла, проект успешно запускался.
Достаточно ли удалить все что находится в теге Compile? И что делать с файлами, которые находятся в теге  DependentUpon?
Я комментировал все что находилось между тегами Compile и если там еще находил тег DependentUpon, то находил название исходника, заключенного в тег Page и комментировал все вместе с тегом Page.
Кто сталкивался с такой задачей прошу помочь.

Comment: К чему такие сложности? Почему не удалить через VS ? А так да удаляйте элемент нужный <Compile/> и все. Другое дело если от удаляемого элемента зависит еще какой.. тут только вы знаете как поступить.

Comment: @ koks_rs  Потому что удаляемых исходных файлов около 100. Их я удаляю используя скрипт написанный на Python. Проект писал не я. Мне надо только удалить эти исходники и собрать проект. Без них он должен собраться, потому что эти исходники, которые я собираюсь удалять являются избыточными. Так что я не совсем понимаю, что делать с этими зависимостями.

Comment: в секции <DependentUpon> находятся не зависимые от текущего элемента файлы, а наоборот, те файлы от которого зависит текущий. Поэтому просто удаляйте <Compile/> и не трогайте файлы от которых зависит текущий файл.

Comment: @koks_rs то есть если у меня есть такая часть кода   <Compile Include="Views\MainWindowView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindowView.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile> То что мне нужно удалять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вам нужно удалить файл `MainWindowView.xaml.cs`

Удаляйте из .csproj весь элемент , в Вашем случае это:

```
<Compile Include="Views\MainWindowView.xaml.cs"> 
    <DependentUpon>MainWindowView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Ok, файл с кодом `MainWindowView.xaml.cs` удален из проекта. Остался файл с разметкой `MainWindowView.xaml`, обычно они идут парами и не имеют смысла один без другого. Тем не менее, если удалить файл с кодом проект собирается(покрайней мере у меня). Нужно ли Вам теперь удалить из проекта `MainWindowView.xaml`  - я не знаю. Ответ зависит от того зачем вы вообще это делаете. Но сдается мне что правильный ответ будет удалить его тоже, таким же методом. Тоесть удалить элемент :

```
<Page Include="MainWindowView.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
```

Comment: Библиотека ресурсов "ResourceDictionary.xaml" идет без сопутствующего "ResourceDictionary.xaml.cs" и имеет без него смысл.

Answer (score 1):

Почему нельзя удалить через IDE? Но если интересна структура, то вообще достаточно удалить тег`<Compile Include="ВашКласс.cs" />` в  `<ItemGroup>` и  если в коде этот класс не используется, то все должно собраться(не удаляйте те классы которые используются у вас в проекте.)

Comment: Потому что удаляемых исходных файлов около 100. А как быть с зависимыми файлами, которые заключены в тег DependentUpon? Их тоже удалять? Если да, то у меня после удаления всех исходников из тега Compile и DependentUpon возникают ошибки вида: Не удалось найти тип или пространство имен "..."

Comment: @user200355: Ну и что, что 100? Сто раз нажать на клавишу Del — это меньше, чем набрать 437 символов вашего вопроса.

Comment: @VladD ок, их 2000. А мне нужно это автоматизировать. Чтобы потом написать скрипт, который будет удалять все теги Compile и Page.

Comment: @user200355: Тогда вы что-то делаете не так. Во-первых, почему в проекте 2000 файлов? Если их так много, имеет смысл разбить на части руками. Ну и апдейт проекта — слишком важная задача, чтобы отлаживать на ней скрипты.